# getting segmentation fault when trying to print first value of array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int * get_arr(int max_val) {
    int arr[max_val];
    arr[0] = 1;
    printf("%d\n", arr[0]);
    return arr;
}

// a function that appears to have nothing to do with i and pt
int some_other_function() {
    int junk = 999;
    return junk;
}

int main () {

    int *pt = get_arr(10); 
    printf("access before: %d\n", *pt);

    // try this program with and without this function call 
    some_other_function();


    printf("but if I try to access i now via *pt I get %d\n", *pt);
    printf("here\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run this code, I get a `segmentation fault` after printing `1` (so basically, a segmentation fault when running this `printf("access before: %d\n", *pt);`). When I remove the line

```
printf("access before: %d\n", *pt);
```

I still get a segmentation fault here `printf("but if I try to access i now via *pt I get %d\n", *pt);`. Any idea why I'm getting a segmentation fault?

Comment: Compiler warning: "returning address of local variable." When `get_arr` returns, `arr[]` ceases to exist.

Comment: @WeatherVane But I thought when passing array as parameters, a pointer to the first element of the array gets passed?

Comment: @WeatherVane Also, after `some_other_function()` is called, shouldn't `*pt` end up pointing to `999`?

Comment: You are not passing an array, you are returning a pointer which has **gone out of scope**, the variable `arr` no longer exists, yet the caller uses it as if it does exist.

Comment: No, it does not. It is undefined what it points to, since `arr` no longer exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the value of arr on the heap, not the stack. When you call `some_other_function()` the values of arr are being overwritten because the other function has ended and the memory allocated is no longer guaranteed to be there.

Try this:

```
int * get_arr(int max_val) {
    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * max_val);
    arr[0] = 1;
    printf("%d\n", arr[0]);
    return arr;
}
```

Just remember to call `free(pt);` when you are done using the array.